# MySQL 8.0.11 is throwing CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Tags: java, mysql, maven, sqlexception

I am new to Java. I created Java Maven project and am getting the below error while connecting to MySQL. I am posting my code below.

In pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

In class,

```
 private void connection() {
     try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.100.00.00:3305/dbname" , 
                                    "username","password");     
     }
     catch(SQLException ex) {       
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

     }
     catch(Exception ex) {      
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

It was throwing **java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required** from SQLException.

Comment: Upgrade your J  connector https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-whats-new.html

Comment: I ended up just creating the database first which resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of the java mysql connector driver being incompartible with the installed version of MYSQL DB.

Kindly check answer posted by @P Satish Patro on this post:
[Spring boot CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192560/spring-boot-client-plugin-auth-is-required)